# How to Send PictureBox image via webSocket

Tags: c#, websocket, byte, picturebox

I need some assistance with this code. I'm Capturing a Desktop screen and showing it in a PictureBox, that works fine, but I'm trying to convert that PictureBox image into bytes[] and then into a string, so then I can send it via WebSocket (ws).

1.) My first problem is, the PictureBox that was drawn with an image it won't convert into byte[] or binary, what am I doing wrong there?, any way around this?

2.) Then the second issue I'm having is, I need to convert those byte[] to a string so then I can send them along with other strings, in the receiving application, I'll split the strings using a separator, and then I'll convert the string to byte[] and then into a picturebox

```
WebSocket ws;

// Here goes the rest of the websocket code, which it works just fine.

private void Display(Bitmap desktop)
{
    Graphics g;
    Rectangle r;
    if (desktop != null)
    {
        // Here I'm capturing the desktop screen and filling the PictureBox1 with it.
        r = new Rectangle(0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height);
        g = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawImage(desktop, r);
        g.Flush();

        // Here I'm trying to convert the filled PictureBox into Byte[]
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(PictureBox1.Image, typeof(byte[]));

        // Here I'm trying to conver the byte[] into a string text
        string bytesString1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(imageBytes);
        string firstString = "1504";
        string separator = "+";

        // Here I'm sending the message via Websocket, which includes the "firstString",
        // the "separator" so then we can use Split in the receiving application, and 
        // then the "bytesString1" which contains the image data.
        string messageToSend = firstString + separator + bytesString1;
        ws.Send(messageToSend);
    }

}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't draw the `Bitmap` onto the `PictureBox` but rather assign it to the `Image` property.  If you must use GDI+ to draw the `Bitmap` onto the `PictureBox` then you'll have to store that `Bitmap` somewhere for later use.  Either way, you need an `Image` object (note that `Bitmap` inherits `Image`).

Create a `MemoryStream` and call `Save` on your `Image` to save it to the stream.  You can then call `GetBuffer` on that stream to get a `byte` array.  Generally you would transmit that `byte` array but, if you need a `string`, call `Convert.ToBase64String`.